# Cloud Functions with Google Maps APIs

Tags: google-maps, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've searched a lot around the web, but didn't found any solution.

Is there a way to use the Google Maps APIs inside Cloud Functions?

For example to verify the existence of a Google Maps Place-Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Looks like my npm was a bit confused (?) with the two `package.json` files. However this is possible.

1. I've run `npm prune` inside both folders:

   1. `functions` folder created by firebase,
   2. initial project folder.
2. Then I've removed the `node_modules` subdirectories from both paths.
3. Checked both `package.json`'s and added manually the firebase dependency to the `package.json` inside the `functions` folder.
4. Installed the `package.json` in both directories.
5. Reuploaded the cloud functions with  `require('@google/maps')`
6. It worked! :)

Thanks for Your support @Frank!

Cheers,

Unkn0wn0x

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Functions are snippets of JavaScript that are executed in a fairly standard Node.js environment. So any time you wonder if you can do a specific thing in Cloud Functions, it helps to search for how to do that same thing in Node.js.

For example a quick search on [`use google maps api in node.js`](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+google+maps+api+in+node.js&oq=use+google+maps+api+in+node.js) leads to many promising results, including this seemingly [authoritative library from the Google Maps team](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js).

Comment: If I try to deploy the functions to the cloud, firebase throws the following error in my console:

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '@google/maps'

Comment: It sounds like you didn't save the google maps dependency to your `package.json`. One way to do that is `npm install @google/maps --save`.

Comment: The dependency for @google/maps exists in my package.json, it throws the same error anyway :(. firebase-tools, firebase-functions and firebase-admin is installed too.